# Does Android Wear support in app purchasing

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

Does Android Wear support in app purchasing?

I'm unable to get my project to compile when I compile with google-playservices-wearable

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
```

however I can compile without the wearable version

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the in-app purchases in the handheld?

You can just use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

in the mobile module and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
```

in the wear module.

`'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'` seems to be a subset.

Comment: you are right, i also needed to add to my gradle: sourceSets {
        main {
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }

Comment: @MobileMon I have no idea about this, unfortunately. I would suggest opening a separate question, since (I guess) it's a different issue.